# Unable to get all the folders and files (under all level) inside a main folder using CAML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, caml

I have the following CAML query inside my sharepoint online remote event receiver where i am trying to get all the files and folders that are directly and indirectly added to the folder named FolderA:-

```
camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem6 = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs").GetItems(camlQuery6);
context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
      item => item.Id,
      item=>item["FileDirRef"],
      item => item["Title"],
      item => item["DealStage"]));
```

the above CAML will only return the main folder under /sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA, but will not return any of the sub-folders and files.. so can anyone advice how i need to modify the CAML, or CAML does not support this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below solution:

```
var _List = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDoc3");
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                     <Query>
                                     </Query>
                                 </View>";
                Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/lee/MyDoc3/ParentFolder");
                context.Load(folder);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                ListItemCollection listItems = _List.GetItems(camlQuery);
                context.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
                      item => item.Id,
                      item => item["FileDirRef"],
                      item => item["FileRef"],
                      item => item["Title"]));

                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is only returning items directly in that folder because your CAML is set to only return items where the `FileDirRef` (or Folder Path) is equal to `/sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA`, anything that is in a subfolder would have a different `FileDirRef`, such as  `/sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA/SubFolder1`, which would not be **equal** to the path you specified.  What you want to do, is instead of the `<Eq>` operator element, you want to use `<BeginsWith>`.

**Note**, you also appear to have syntax error with your string concatenation `context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA"</Value>`

Give this a try:

```
camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA" + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem6 = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs").GetItems(camlQuery6);
context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
      item => item.Id,
      item=>item["FileDirRef"],
      item => item["Title"],
      item => item["DealStage"]));
```